# Nesting Levels in Custom Section Handlers in .NET Configuration Files

Tags: .net, app-config, configuration-files

I know I can have 1 parent element and 1 child element in my own custom app.config section like so:

```
<sectionGroup>
<section>
    <element />
</section>
</sectionGroup>
```

My question is, can I have one or more levels of nesting more than this? Like so:

```
<biggestSectionGroup>
<biggerSectionGroup>
<sectionGroup>
    <section>
        <element />
    </section>
</sectionGroup>
</biggerSectionGroup>
</biggestSectionGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

There is a series of (slightly old but still very good) articles ([part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx), [part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx) & [part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)) on CodeProject that describe everything you could want to know about config files. They describe in detail how to attain what you describe.

Comment: Thanks very much, adrianbanks.

I am in a hurry at the moment, to finish a code base and prefer a smaller article. Or, better yet, one of the heirarchies I need to implement in my app.config is this:

<DataCollectionPolicy get="*|none|all">
<Exceptions>
<add name="DataManagerName" value="true|false" />
</Exceptions>
</DataCollectionPolicy>

I'd be delighted if you could tell me how to write a custom config section handler for this one.

I do know how to implement one for 1 level of nesting.

Comment: I'm trying. May be I can. I'll let you know if I have a problem.